# Component.Apex.InputField error: Error is in expression

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, exception

I get error below when I click on submit button of VisualForce page. Data loads perfectly into page. But submit button click causes exception below. Any idea why this is popping up?

> Unknown property 'SObject.Description' Error is in expression
>   '{!FormObject.Description}' in component  in page
>   FormDisplay

There is no code in SaveData method which is being called from Action of the submit button. FormObject is type of SObject initialised with a Contact using,

```
    FormObject = (Contact)Database.query('SELECT ID,Description 
FROM Contact LIMIT 1 WHERE ID = "0032600000Jfr9C"');
```

SaveData method:

```
public PageReference saveData(){

    try{
        //upsert FormObject;

        if (show_thankyou)
            return new PageReference('https://salesforce-instance/apex/Thank_You');

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Info, 'Error: ' + ex));
    }

    return null;
}
```

Any clue to look at? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your code please?

Comment: Kindly add some apex and VF code using which we can reproduce